Times of a hidden order
The goal is to find the 6th time of a set of six different times on a clock. In order for this set of times to be complete, what time must replace the question mark? As usual, explain why.



Just want to say, so to not waste your time, notice the lack of "sequence"-tag. Hence why I used "set" instead. The set you see is simply arranged in "time of the day"-order, starting with the earliest to latest. Also, try to make sense of the title.

The times on the clocks are

 131, 232, 235, 711, 719

This set may be

 rearranged as: 235 711 131 719 232
 which splits into 2, 3, 5, 7, 11,  13, 17, 19 23, 2

So a 6th time would be

 931 to continue the sequence of primes

The title may clue how the

  times are rearranged. I see ORDER, rearranged alphabetically to DEORR to clue this?


Correct, well done! The title was just clueing "hidden order" (order of p's). These are all 6 times possible in order since the next would be 3:74
